# How can I make a control panel accessable only from a subdomain & port?

Tags: nginx

Currently in my configuration I have set up a domain `example.com` to connect to a website. Then  have `control.example.com` connect to a control panel with the 2054 port. So, to access the control panel it would be `https://control.example.com:2054`; however, for some reason I can also access the control panel by going to `https://example.com:2054` without the subdomain.

Is there a way to prevent this, and only make https://control.example.com:2054/ while preventing https://example.com:2054/ from accessing?

Comment: Yes. Edit your question to contain your configuration files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent this, and only make https://control.example.com:2054/ while preventing https://example.com:2054/ from accessing?

Yes. The simplest way likely is to use Nginx as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). A basic overview of using Nginx in this capacity can be found [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/).

In short, you would want to set up two server blocks similar to the following:

```
# Block access to example.com:2054, assuming Nginx is servicing that port.
#
server {
    listen       2054;
    server_name  example.com;

    # 404 - Not Found is returned, but 403 - Forbidden is another option
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

# another (unblocked) virtual host on the same port e.g. control.example.com:2054
#
server {
    listen       2054;
    server_name  control.example.com;

    # Proxy our web data
    location / {
    proxy_pass      http://10.0.0.10:3005;
    }
}
```

This example assumes two different ports are in use since this setup is easy to deal with. The port you want to publicly access the service with should be forwarded, the internal (actual) service port should not. The `proxy_pass` IP should (obviously) be the IP of the PC running the service you wish to access.

In case the solution above is not a good fit for you, note that you may be able to do something with [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) or similar.